# Should I make game engines to be a good "game programmer", or is it more important to build games with Unity/Unreal?

Tags: unity, unreal

Do I need to make game engines to be a good "game programmer" in general, or is it more important to build games with Unity/Unreal and learn coding along the way or both?

I am going into a Computer Science program and want to be a software developer, preferably in the Game Industry.

I was thinking I should learn C++ first as it is the most used in Game Development and then try to make my own Game.

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to know how to make *games*, use a pre-existing engine. If you want to learn how to make *game engines*, it might be good practice to write one yourself. Or do both: even if you prefer one, having a knowledge of the field nearby is useful. (Concentrate on your studies too though! :))

Comment: You should read the help page to see what's on-topic at this site. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help Your question is a forum-style question, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: Even if this is offtopic here I'll throw in my 2 cents: I'm in a similar situation and recently started building up my own engine (or call it framework, it's not advanced enough to be called engine yet) with c++ and DirectX. I think this is the right decision, as you'll have it much easier working with your own "engine" than something pre-existing. Also you can adjust it to your individual needs. It's some really good practise.

Comment: This is mostly opinion-based, but many people like to quote the article [Write Games, Not Engines](http://www.geometrian.com/programming/tutorials/write-games-not-engines/index.php) by Josh Petrie

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. If you have ideas for a game and want to do that, then use an already existing engine. I've been building my own because I wanted to know engines worked.

Comment: If you haven't built any games before to know what you need and the limitations of the many decisions you are going to have then your engine is going to suck. That should answer the question quite clearly. The off the shelf engines won't do everything you want, so you'll eventually need to dive into details anyways and learn some of the innards of game engines along the way. But at least then you'll have a clue why you are adding/modifying the feature and what it needs to do in order to actually be usable.

Comment: This question is not productive with respect to this forum. The reason is this will not benefit people coming after you. Please delete this post.

Comment: If your focus is to release a game, use an Engine that fit your needs. If you're doing that to learn how games are made, try making your own engine.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is opinion based. A game engine is used by a game developer/designer. To make a good engine you have to know how a game developer/designer uses an engine. Best way to learn that is by being a game developer/designer. So design a game first, write an engine later. Or the engine will be rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spend a lot of time with a big team, go make your own. But if you are an indie developer with a little time, Unreal Engine would be a better choice because light building and rendering and core classes are done by the engine. After all, if you really spend your time on making your own and it turns out great, it will pottentialy have a better performance because only the things for your game are made and not other classes for other games. A good thing to know is that Unreal engine is multiplatform.